# Highlight words in richtextbox

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how I can highlight multiple words in a richtextbox, in example

words im searching is "la"
in the text "la langue";

I have this code here

```
private void Surligne(string[] mots)
    {
        foreach (string word in mots)
        {
            int Index = 0;
            while (Index < rtb.TextLength)
            {
                int wordStartIndex = rtb.Find(word, Index, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                if (wordStartIndex != -1)
                {
                    rtb.SelectionStart = wordStartIndex;
                    rtb.SelectionLength = word.Length;
                    rtb.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                }
                else
                    break;
                Index += wordStartIndex + word.Length;
            }
        }
    }
```

but it highlights la 'la'ngue

I only want it to highlight la and not 'la'langue.

How can I change my code to do this? thanks.

Comment: Check what the characters before and after the match are. If it's a space or doesn't exist then you know you've found the whole word. Alternatively, use a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comment from @sab669, these are the 2 ways suggested, in code. The exact result will depend on how exactly you define a word (can a number be a part of the word? what about connectors such as underscore?), but for most cases these should work the same.

**1. Checking the adjacent characters**

This only needs a modification of your `while` loop. You have to check the adjacent characters, keeping in mind that you might be at the start or end of the string:

```
while (Index < rtb.TextLength)
{
    int wordStartIndex = rtb.Find(word, Index, System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    if (wordStartIndex == -1) 
        break;
    if ((wordStartIndex == 0 || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(rtb.Text[wordStartIndex - 1])) &&
        (wordStartIndex + word.Length >= rtb.TextLength || !char.IsLetterOrDigit(rtb.Text[wordStartIndex + word.Length])))
    {
        rtb.SelectionStart = wordStartIndex;
        rtb.SelectionLength = word.Length;
        rtb.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    }
    Index += wordStartIndex + word.Length;
}
```

**2. Using a regular expression**

This results in a bit shorter code and fortunately the regular expression is not so difficult:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, "\\b" + word + "\\b"))
{
    rtb.SelectionStart = match.Index;
    rtb.SelectionLength = word.Length;
    rtb.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
}
```

I used `\b`, which denotes a boundary between a word character and non-word character. For more info you can look at the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/az24scfc(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx), which will also have information on what exactly these characters are.